# Apache AllowOverride directive

Tags: php, apache

There's a server for which I don't have access to the control panel; I can only access a directory by FTP.
I need to know if the Apache AllowOverride directive is enabled in that directory.
I want to check that Apache has mod rewrite enabled and that the options allow Override All.
How do I do it with a PHP script?
Thanks

Comment: For which override? Also, I don't think you can check this from PHP

Comment: I want to check that Apache has mod rewrite enabled and that the options allow Override All

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any way to do that in PHP.  The only way is to put some commands into .htaccess that depend on AllowOverride and mod_rewrite, and see if you get 500 Internal Server Error when you visit the directory by web.  For example, you can put

```
Options all
```

to test `AllowOverride Options`,

```
Allow from all
```

to test `AllowOverride Limit`, or

```
RewriteRule .* -
```

(which does nothing) to test mod_rewrite.